# TSQL: Best way to get data from temp/scratch table to normalized version?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm working in with relatively large data sets; ~200GB.  The data is coming from text files that are being imported to SQL via a script.  They are being bulkcopy'd into a temp table with the normalized tables waiting to recieve the data.

My question comes from the fact that I'm mostly a scripter so my logic would be to loop through each row and do individual checks per row to put the data where it needs to go but I read a different post on SO saying that's really wrong for SQL.

So my question is, if I have one temp table (31 columns) that is to be normalized between 5 others, what's the best way to go about this?

Table relationship is as follows:

System - Table that contains machine information (e.g. name, domain, etc.)

File - File information (e.g. name, size, directory, etc.)

SystemFile - The many-to-many system<->file relationship table.

Metadata - File metadata (language, etc.) - has foreign key relationship to file primary key

DigitalSignature - File digital signature status - has foreign key relationship to file primary key

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered an ETL tool here?  I was in a similiar position a few years back...made everything work with Pentaho

Comment: Rather then check each row put that in the where of a TSQL query.

Comment: Be methodical.  You may need extra fields in your staging table to store things such as the existance of existing records and default values for when the data in your text file does not pass muster.  Then run insert or update queries to populate your production tables.  Make sure you populate your parent tables first so that you don't have foreign key problems.

Comment: As a professional ETL developer, I recommend just writing the correct T-SQL upsert queries to push data in the manner Dan prescribes. ETL is overkill for a straightforward normalization process.

Comment: Dan -- but my question is more about how would I got about doing what you said?  Do I process every individual row and normalize all the data or is there a way to use SQL queries to do something like what gordatron said but also including the index association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont have any links, don't have enough experience with things like ssis etc to give a balanced view. but when doing the task you are talking about my normal process would be (generic, simple version):

1.look at normalised data set and consider the least dependant components in the data being imported (e.g. order headers created before order items)

2.create queries the select out the data i will have.. these often have this form:

```
 select
    t.x,t.y,t.z
 from
    temp_table as t
    left outer join normalise_table as n
        on t.x=n.x
        and t.y=n.y
        and t.z=n.z
 where
    n.x is null
```

where temp_table may have lots of columns but these three represent whatever normalised nugget i want to add first, the left outer join and where null make sure i only get the new values - if merging is the same

verify that i am getting good information and that i am only getting the new rows i want. often you have to use group bys or distincts on the temp data to get accurate data for inserting.. something like:

```
 select
    t.x,t.y,t.z
 from
    (select 
        distinct x,y,z
     from    
         temp_table ) as t
    left outer join normalise_table as n
        on t.x=n.x
        and t.y=n.y
        and t.z=n.z
 where
    n.x is null
```

3.wrap that select in an insert:

```
  insert into 
     normalise_table (x,y,z)
  select
    t.x,t.y,t.z
 from
    (select 
        distinct x,y,z
     from    
         temp_table ) as t
    left outer join normalise_table as n
        on t.x=n.x
        and t.y=n.y
        and t.z=n.z
 where
    n.x is null
```

in this way you are inserting sets of data.. the procedural part is doing this for each set to be inserted, but in general you are not iterating over rows.

BTW T-SQL has a merge command for when you may or may not have the data in the target table (and if you want to remove keys missing from the temp tables)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

**Some comments on foreign keys** - these tend to be more specific to the situation:

Can you identify the relationship without the primary key? This is the easiest situation to deal with..

Imagine I have inserted my xyz object into a normalised table but it has 100 child rows (abc's) in another table (each child may have 100 children too.. this would mean 10000 rows in the de-normalised data for one xyz)

you would have to go through the validation before but your final query may look something like:

```
insert into 
    normalise_table_2 (parentID,a,b,c)
select
    n.id,t.a,t.b,t.c
from
   (select 
       distinct x,y,z,a,b,c
   from    
       temp_table ) as t
   inner join join normalise_table as n
       on t.x=n.x
       and t.y=n.y
       and t.z=n.z
   left outer join normalise_table_2 as n2
       on n.id = n2.parentID
       and t.a = n2.a
       and t.b = n2.b
       and t.c = n2.c
where
    n2.a is null
```

or maybe a more readable way:

```
insert into normalise_table_2 (parentID,a,b,c)
select
    *
from (
    select distinct
        n.id,t.a,t.b,t.c
    from
        normalise_table as n
        inner join temp_table as t
            on t.x = n.x
            and t.y = n.y
            and t.z = n.z
        left outer join normalise_table_2 as n2
            on t.a = n2.a
            and t.b = n2.b
            and t.c = n2.c
            and n2.parentID = n.id
        where
            n2.id is null
    ) as x
```

If you are having trouble identifying the row without the id here are some points to consider

1. I often give a unique id to every row in the de-normalised/import data this makes it easier to track what has and has not been done. not to mention paying off in other ways (e.g. when source data has blanks if its they are to be the same as the row above)
2. I have created temp tables to track relationships like this as I go along.

   - sometimes (especially for less consistent data) these are not temp tables as they can be used after the fact for analysis what did and didn't import (and where it went), sometimes i have a comments column that the update queries populate with any details about exceptions relating to the import of that row.
3. sometimes you are lucky and there is some kind of source or oldId field in the target that can be used to link the de-normalised data and normalised version (this is particularly true of system migration type tasks as people often want to be able to look up items in the old system). sometimes this can be weird and wonderful - e.g. using the updated by or created by field looking for a special account that executes this particular process (though i would not particulary recommend that)
4. Sometimes it makes sense to update the source tables in some way.. e.g. replacing identifiers there
5. Sometimes you come up with ID ranges or similar that are used for import and you break normal rules about where ids are generated and your import process creates the ID.

   - this often means shutting down all other access to the target system while the import is executed. may sound mad but sometimes this is the best way for very complex uploads that require a lot of preparation

But often when you think about it there is a particular order you can add your data in and avoid this issue as you will always be able to identify the correct data.  I have used the above techniques to make my life easier but I am not sure I have ever HAD to use them..

The only exception I can think of is generating IDs outside of the system which i have had to use, but this was so that IDs would be consistent across multiple trial loads and the final production load.  Also data was coming from many sources with many people working on it, it made life easier that they could be in control of their own IDs - but it did bring other issues ;).

Generally I would try and leave the source data alone and ensure that if you re-run any of your scripts then they wont have any effect.  this makes the whole system much more robust and gives everyone more confidence as you can re-import the same data or a file that has some of the same data and run everything again and nothing breaks.

note i have not tested any of these queries and just written them off the top of my head so sorry if they are not totally accurate.

Comment: So I got this far gordatron -- it's good to see you understand what I'm trying to do.  However, I'm still missing how you would take the un-normalized data from the temp table, normalize it across many different tables, but also build the key associations necessary to rejoin the data once it's been normalized.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't clearly write out that request as I just re-read my post so thank you for amending your answer.